# Skimage.feature.hog find dominant orientation

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am currently attempting to extract the dominant orientation of a given image with the skimage.feature.hog function.

This is the function I am currently using:

```
from skimage.feature import hog
fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=36, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8),
                    cells_per_block=(3, 3), visualize=True, multichannel=False, feature_vector=False)
```

and it outputs me a matrix with the shape: `(6, 6, 3, 3, 36)`.
While the visualization shows that the "correct" orientation is extracted, I do not know how to compute a single angle from the matrix.

[image: Visualization]